# How to return a string from a text file with condition met?

Tags: vb.net, list, streamreader

[image]

```
 Public Sub openDB()
        Dim Lines As New List(Of String)

        Try
            ' Open the file using a stream reader.
            Using sr As New StreamReader("Config.txt")
                Dim line As String
                ' Read the stream to a string and write the string to the console.
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                Do Until String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
                    Lines.Add(line)
                    line = sr.ReadLine
                Loop
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try

        Dim dbname As String = g_DatabaseName
        Dim server As String = Lines.Where(Function(str) str.Contains("server =")).ToString
        Dim user As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""

        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false; Convert Zero Datetime=True", server, user, password, dbname)
        conn.Open()
    End Sub
```

Im try to return some string from a text file, so I use StreamReader to read the file and store them into a list. Now I try to declare a variable to get "localhost" from list of string, but the code below is not work for me.

> Dim server As String = Lines.Where(Function(str) str.Contains("server
>   =")).ToString

Comment: What does the server string give you in return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Where` does not return a single string but possibly multiple, using `ToString` gives you not the first matching line but just the name of the type which is `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator1[System.String]`.

Either declare it as `IEnumerable(Of String)`  or use `First`/ `FirstOrDefault` to get the first line that matches the condition:

```
Dim serverLine As String = Lines
    .Where(Function(str) str.Contains("server ="))
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

You can also use the overload of `FirstOrDefault`(`Nothing` if there was no such line):

```
Dim serverLine As String = Lines.FirstOrDefault(Function(str) str.Contains("server ="))
```

To extract `Localhost`:

```
Dim server As String = serverLine.Substring(serverLine.IndexOf("server =") + "server =".Length).Trim(""""c, " "c)
```

Comment: To fast for me to have time to reply haha. I like the FirstOrDefault approach vote up!